# Sidekiq + Carrierwave - MiniMagick Processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, carrierwave

Hi Ive setup a stable service that handles photo uploads and processes these uploads using `Carrierwave` into 3 versions and uploads them to `S3` using `Fog`. Initially I upload photos to `S3` and use `remote_resource_url` to do the processing and stuff.

Here is my worker of `Sidekiq`:

```rb
class ResourceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    photo = Photo.find(id)
    if photo.resource.blank?
      photo.remote_resource_url = photo.original_resource_url
      photo.resource_processed = true
      photo.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I am using Rubber + Capistrano for deployment and I am using the default Sidekiq configuration given by Rubber which is 25 workers running at a time.

Everything was working fine until this weekend where we got a lot of uploads and the server completely slowed down. Its a `m1.medium` instance EC2 having a single core CPU with 4 GB of RAM.

When I checked the processes using `htop` the CPU was at 100% usage and so was the RAM. When I turned off sidekiq, everything went back to normal. I can see that the `morgify` was taking a lot of CPU.

When I checked the Sidekiq logs I can see a lot of these errors:

```
2014-05-05T13:22:27Z 11409 TID-voce4 WARN: 
{"retry"=>true, 
"queue"=>"default", 
"class"=>"ResourceWorker", 
"args"=>[29228], 
"jid"=>"4d6424ce3e28b5339c3828e8", 
"enqueued_at"=>1399278674.4943266, "error_message"=>"Validation failed: Resource Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command (\"mogrify -auto-orient /tmp/mini_magick20140505-11409-1p246jf.jpg\") failed: {:status_code=>nil, :output=>\"\"}", 
"error_class"=>"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid", 
"failed_at"=>"2014-05-05T08:31:22Z", 
"retry_count"=>6, 
"retried_at"=>2014-05-05 13:22:23 UTC}
2014-05-05T13:22:27Z 11409 TID-voce4 WARN: Validation failed: Resource Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command ("mogrify -auto-orient /tmp/mini_magick20140505-11409-1p246jf.jpg") failed: {:status_code=>nil, :output=>""}
2014-05-05T13:22:27Z 11409 TID-voce4 WARN: /mnt/snapshot-production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
```

These images are all > 3 MB in size. I dont know why these errors are happening all of a sudden now. And they dont seem to be running at all anymore. They keep failing. If I try a manual operation with `mogrify` or `convert` or `identify` it all passes and my `imagemagick` has delegates for png and jpeg/jpg. So thats not the problem I assume.

I really dont know what to do as it is blocking out the whole service and my Rails app cannot run at all. I am going to move image processing to a separate instance now. But I dont have a solution to these failures.

Thanks in advance.

And yeah my uploader:

```rb
# encoding: utf-8

class ResourceUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # storage set in initializers/carrierwave.rb
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :auto_orient

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fit: [nil, 400]
    process :quality => 40
  end

  version :small, from_version: :large do
    process resize_to_fit: [nil, 120]
    process :quality => 30
    process :get_version_dimensions  
  end



  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def get_version_dimensions
    if @file && model.class == Photo
      image = MiniMagick::Image.open @file.file 
      if model
        model.small_version_width = image[:width]
        model.small_version_height = image[:height]
      end
    end
  end

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient
      img
    end
  end


  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png gif)
  end


end
```

Also: without any load!!!:

[image]